# Threadpool size to number of cores available

Tags: node.js, performance

Will changing the thread pool size to the number of CPU cores available automatically make NodeJS multithreaded processes (crypto, fs, etc) run faster? If yes, how do I make it do so automatically?

```js
 process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=require('os').cpus().length;
```

Will this work on any kind of server?

I don't see why thread pool size is not already automatically set to the number of cores?

Comment: It is a bit clumsy that libuv does not do this automatically.  But justifiable, it is not so common that a machine is dedicated to only running a node app.  It will only have an affect if the node app manages to start more than 4 of those tasks at the same time.  That is not easy to do.  Just try it.